# GDB remote debugging with valgrind

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, valgrind

If I remote debug using `gdb` I connect to the `gdbserver` using

```
target remote host:2345
```

If I debug memory errors with valgrind and gdb (to break on invalid memory access) I use

```
target remote | vgdb
```

(after starting

```
valgrind --track-origins=yes --vgdb=yes --vgdb-error=0 [binary]
```

on the local machine)

Can I combine the two to debug memory errors on a remote machine?

Note that I want to avoid using a login shell on the remote machine to work there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can I combine the two to debug memory errors on a remote machine?

Yes: current vgdb accepts `--port=` argument since this commit:

```
r12204 | sewardj | 2011-10-22 13:38:08 -0700 (Sat, 22 Oct 2011) | 5 lines
```

So run `vgdb --port=2345`, and then `(gdb) target remote host:2345` as usual.

Comment: I found time now to try this: `( valgrind --track-origins=yes --vgdb=yes --vgdb-error=0  $opt_executable $opt_executable_args | tee $myprogramlog; ) &
sleep 5; vgdb --port=2345` I get: `listening on port 2345 ...connected. relaying data between gdb and process 4853` and then `(gdb) target remote host:2345` the processes terminate .. So I can't debug with it, not even run it. Any ideas?